# Display validation message in alert prompt using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I need one help.I need to display all validation messages in alert prompt instead of using `ng-message` using Angular.js.First let me explain my form code.

```
<form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
<div id="SHOWDATA">
<div id="transactionsPortlet" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<div class="portlet-body">
<div class="totalaligndiv">
<div class="col-md-6">

<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">College Title :</span>
<input type="text" name="colgmname" id="procolgtitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Add College Title" ng-model="colgname" >
</div> 

<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">College subtitle :</span>
<input type="text" name="shortname" id="procolgsubtitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Add College subtitle" ng-model="shortname" >
</div> 
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Contact No :</span>
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error': billdata.mobno.$touched && billdata.mobno.$invalid }">
<input type="text" name="mobno" id="procolgcontactno" class="form-control" placeholder="Add contact no" ng-model="contno"  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10,10}$/" >
</div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.mobno.$error" ng-if="billdata.mobno.$touched">
<p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs only number(e.g-0,1..9) and also no decimal values are allowed.</p>
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Email Address :</span>
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error': billdata.email.$touched && billdata.email.$invalid }">
<input type="email" name="email" id="procolgmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Add email id" ng-model="colgemail" ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/" >
</div>
</div>

<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.email.$error" ng-if="billdata.email.$touched">
<p ng-message="email" style="color:#F00;">This needs to be a valid email</p>
<p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs valid email format(e.g-abc@gmail.com).</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">College Code :</span>
<input type="text" name="colgcode" id="procolgcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Add college code" ng-model="colgcode" >
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">College Address :</span>
<textarea id="procolgaddress" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Add College Address" rows="5" ng-model="address" style="height:122px"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>    
<div style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px;">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addProfileData(billdata);"  id="addProfileData" ng-value="Add"/>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>    

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>  
</form>
```

Here my requirement is if user will click on `ADD` button without filling the form the field required  message will come in alert prompt in stead of using `ng-message`.Similarly for other validation like `email,contact no` should come in alert prompt when click on button.only red border line will display at the required field if any error will occur but the message will display after click on the button.Please help me.

Comment: So there will be multiple consecutive alerts?

Comment: @dfsq : Suppose without filling the form user clicked on add button the message required field needs value will display in alert prompt.Suppose any pattern related error will come it should display also after click on add button in alert prompt.

Comment: This is quite bad in terms of UX. You should probably not go this way.

Comment: @dfsq : I know but requirement is like this.

Comment: You need to explain people in charge why this requirement is shit. But if you still need to do it like this, you need to write a custom directive. Or simple watcher for `$error` collection or `$invalid` on the form controller.

Comment: @dfsq : Can you give one simple example or create a plunkr for this.